# How to have negative zero always formatted as positive zero in a python string?

Tags: python

I have the following to format a string:

```
'%.2f' % n
```

If `n` is a negative zero (`-0`, `-0.000` etc) the output will be `-0.00`.

How do I make the output always `0.00` for both negative and positive zero values of `n`?

(It is fairly straight forward to achieve this but I cannot find what I would call a succinct pythonic way. Ideally there is a string formatting option that I am not aware of.)

Comment: [x + (-0) = x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero#Arithmetic)

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0682/ Added to Python 3.11

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Add zero:

```
>>> a = -0.0
>>> a + 0
0.0
```

which you can format:

```
>>> '{0:.3f}'.format(a + 0)
'0.000'
```

Comment: This actually made me laugh out loud. Wonderful.

Comment: In your example you can change `0.` to `0`.

Comment: Amazing. Even though I'm sure someone will read some code using this trick and will think "Why the hell does he add zero to all his floats?!"

Answer (score 8):

A very closely related problem is that -0.00001 is also formatted as "-0.00". That can be just as confusing. The answers above will not take care of this (except for user278064's, which needs an anchored regexp).

It's ugly, but this is the best I can do for this case:

```
import re
re.sub (r"^-(0\.?0*)$", r"\1", "%.2f" % number)
```

Comment: if round(v * 1000) == 0: v= 0.0

Comment: For my example, I guess you mean `v*100`. Maybe a simpler version is:
`if round(v,2) == 0: v= 0.0` . The problem is that this changes the value of v after the print, which is not good. So how about: `"%.2f" % (0.0 if round(v,2) == 0 else v)` .

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way is to specialcase zero in your format:

```
>>> a = -0.0
>>> '%.2f' % ( a if a != 0 else abs(a) )
0.0
```

However, do note that the `str.format` method is preferred over `%` substitutions - the syntax in this case (and in most simple cases) is nearly identical:

```
>>> '{:.2f}'.format(a if a != 0 else abs(a))
```

Also note that the more concise `a or abs(a)` doesn't seem to - even though `bool(a)` is `False`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
re.sub("[-+](0\.0+)", r"\1", number)
```

e.g.:

```
re.sub("[-+](0\.0+)", r"\1", "-0.0000") // "0.0000"
re.sub("[-+](0\.0+)", r"\1", "+0.0000") // "0.0000"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x= '{0:.2f}'.format(abs(n) if n==0 else n)
>>> print(x) 
0.00
```

reason for the `if` condition:

```
>>> -0.0000==0
True
>>> 0.000==0
True
>>> 0.0==0
True
```

Comment: @jamylak Ah! I missed the else condition.

Comment: You can shorten it to this `'{0:.2f}'.format(abs(n) if n==0 else n)`

Comment: @jamylak suggestion implemented.