# Why does App Engine show different float rounding results compared to my local machine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

If you put the following into [App Engine Shell](http://shell.appspot.com/) you get `'50.49'`. This result is consistent on both the 2.5 and 2.7 runtimes.

```
 >> a = '%0.2f' % (round(float(u'50.485'), 2),)
 >> a
'50.49'
```

However if I put the same thing into my local MacBook Pro running python 2.7.1 I get `'50.48'`.

```
 >> a = '%0.2f' % (round(float(u'50.485'), 2),)
 >> a
'50.48'
```

Why is this different and how can I get consistency between my local machine and App Engine's servers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, Google App Engine uses "float" C type (IEEE 754 single precision), while local Python uses "double" instead (IEEE 754 double precision).

I have suspected that CPython has a configure switch to use 'float' instead of 'double', but haven't found one.

Comment: This explains why the values are different and Lipis and Asim Ihsan explain how to gain consistency. You can also use numpy.float32.

Answer (score 2):

Funny, this exact topic is covered in the official Python tutorial.

Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

> Other surprises follow from this one. For example, if you try to round
>   the value 2.675 to two decimal places, you get this
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> round(2.675, 2)
> 2.67
> ```
>
> The documentation for the built-in round() function says that it
>   rounds to the nearest value, rounding ties away from zero. Since the
>   decimal fraction 2.675 is exactly halfway between 2.67 and 2.68, you
>   might expect the result here to be (a binary approximation to) 2.68.
>   It’s not, because when the decimal string 2.675 is converted to a
>   binary floating-point number, it’s again replaced with a binary
>   approximation, whose exact value is
>
> ```
> 2.67499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875
> ```
>
> Since this approximation is slightly closer to 2.67 than to 2.68, it’s
>   rounded down.
>
> **If you’re in a situation where you care which way your decimal
>   halfway-cases are rounded, you should consider using the decimal
>   module.** Incidentally, the decimal module also provides a nice way to
>   “see” the exact value that’s stored in any particular Python float
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> from decimal import Decimal
> >>> Decimal(2.675)
> Decimal('2.67499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875')
> ```

One of the articles linked from the official Python tutorial (http://www.lahey.com/float.htm), despite using FORTRAN, correctly describes what IEEE 754 really means:

> Different computers use different numbers of bits to store
>   floating-point numbers. **Even when the same IEEE formats are used for
>   storing numbers, differences in calculations can occur because of the
>   size of intermediate registers.** To increase portability and to ensure
>   consistent results, I recommend against comparing for exact equality
>   of real numbers in FORTRAN.

So if you really care about this then definitely use the built-in decimal module (or the cdecimal module, available here http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cdecimal/2.3, if performance is an issue).

Comment: Thanks @Asmin, I read those docs thoroughly prior to posting the question but did not read the link you posted at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are correct so I won't say anything regarding the behaviour of the `round` function, but if you want to have consistent results you can skip the `round`, since you're using the string format (`'%0.2f'`) as you showed in your example.

```
>> a = '%0.2f' % (float(u'50.485'))
>> a
'50.48'
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The round function was originally part of an attempt to gain consistency with -0 and 0. The original code was '%0.2f' % (round(n, 2) + 0,) so that the results were the same for n = -0.00 and n = 0.00. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010683/how-to-have-negative-zero-always-formatted-as-positive-zero-in-a-python-string for the previous discussion.