# How to handle rounding to negative zero in Python docstring tests

Tags: python, numpy, docstring, doctest

Related to this question: [How to have negative zero always formatted as positive zero in a python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010683/how-to-have-negative-zero-always-formatted-as-positive-zero-in-a-python-string)

I have the following function that implements Matlab's orth.m using Numpy.  I have a docstring test that relies on np.array2string using suppress_small=True, which will make small values round to zero.  However, sometimes they round to positive zero and sometimes they round to negative zero, depending on whether the answer comes out as 1e-16 or -1e-17 or similar.  Which case happens is based on the SVD decomposition, and can vary from platform to platform or across Python versions depending on which underlying linear algebra solver is used (BLAS, Lapack, etc.)

What's the best way to design the docstring test to account for this?

In the final doctest, sometimes the Q[0, 1] term is -0. and sometimes it's 0.

```py
import doctest
import numpy as np

def orth(A):
    r"""
    Orthogonalization basis for the range of A.

    That is, Q.T @ Q = I, the columns of Q span the same space as the columns of A, and the number
    of columns of Q is the rank of A.

    Parameters
    ----------
    A : 2D ndarray
        Input matrix

    Returns
    -------
    Q : 2D ndarray
        Orthogonalization matrix of A

    Notes
    -----
    #.  Based on the Matlab orth.m function.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> import numpy as np

    Full rank matrix
    >>> A = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [-1, -2, 0], [0, 1, -1]])
    >>> r = np.linalg.matrix_rank(A)
    >>> print(r)
    3

    >>> Q = orth(A)
    >>> with np.printoptions(precision=8):
    ...     print(Q)
    [[-0.12000026 -0.80971228  0.57442663]
     [ 0.90175265  0.15312282  0.40422217]
     [-0.41526149  0.5664975   0.71178541]]

    Rank deficient matrix
    >>> A = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]])
    >>> r = np.linalg.matrix_rank(A)
    >>> print(r)
    2

    >>> Q = orth(A)
    >>> print(np.array2string(Q, precision=8, suppress_small=True))  # Sometimes this fails
    [[-0.70710678 -0.        ]
     [ 0.          1.        ]
     [-0.70710678  0.        ]]

    """
    # compute the SVD
    (Q, S, _) = np.linalg.svd(A, full_matrices=False)
    # calculate a tolerance based on the first eigenvalue (instead of just using a small number)
    tol = np.max(A.shape) * S[0] * np.finfo(float).eps
    # sum the number of eigenvalues that are greater than the calculated tolerance
    r = np.sum(S > tol, axis=0)
    # return the columns corresponding to the non-zero eigenvalues
    Q = Q[:, np.arange(r)]
    return Q

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doctest.testmod(verbose=False)
```

Comment: Could using `Q = orth(A) + 0.0` help? Adding `0.0` should change negative zero to positive zero, but leave everything else unaltered.

Comment: That will only work if the value is actually zero.  If it's -1e-17, then it will still round to negative zero.

Comment: Ah, good point. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: pytest has the ability to round floating point numbers using the NUMBER option, but it will no longer be compatible with the built in doctest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print the *rounded* array plus `0.0` to eliminate the `-0`:

```
A = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]])
Q = orth(A)
Q[0,1] = -1e-16   # simulate a small floating point deviation

print(np.array2string(Q.round(8)+0.0, precision=8, suppress_small=True))
#[[-0.70710678  0.        ]
# [ 0.          1.        ]
# [-0.70710678  0.        ]]
```

So your doc string should be:

```
>>> Q = orth(A)
>>> print(np.array2string(Q.round(8)+0.0, precision=8, suppress_small=True)) # guarantee non-negative zeros
[[-0.70710678  0.        ]
 [ 0.          1.        ]
 [-0.70710678  0.        ]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this one.  One advantage here is that you don't even need the suppress_small=True anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative I came up with, although I think I like rounding the array to the given precision better.  In this method, you shift the whole array by some amount that is bigger than the round-off error, but smaller than the precision comparison.  That way the small numbers will still always be slightly positive.

```py
    >>> Q = orth(A)
    >>> print(np.array2string(Q + np.full(Q.shape, 1e-14), precision=8, suppress_small=True))
    [[-0.70710678  0.        ]
     [ 0.          1.        ]
     [-0.70710678  0.        ]]
```