# Bad string representation of negative imaginary numbers in Python

Tags: python, string, complex-numbers, repr

For some reason the string representation of negative imaginary numbers in Python is different for equal values:

```
>>> str(-3j)
'(-0-3j)'
>>> str(0-3j)
'-3j'
```

Moreover, if I try to get the string representation of `-0-3j`, I get:

```
>>> str(-0-3j)
'-3j'
```

Which seems like an inconsistency.

The problem is that I use the string representation of complex scalar tensors to compute the hash of some operators, and because of this inconsistency I get different hashes for equal operators.

Is there any way to convert `'(-0-3j)'` to `'-3j'`?

### Edit:

[Mechanic Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17980931/mechanic-pig) pointed out that:

```
>>> str(-0.-3j)
'(-0-3j)'
```

Comment: If you add the decimal point `-0.-3j`, its result will be `'-0-3j'`, because integers do not distinguish between positive and negative zeros, but floating-point numbers do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is [filed as a bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue45995) and stimulated appearance of [PEP-0682 - Format Specifier for Signed Zero](https://peps.python.org/pep-0682/) and originates from [Floating-point arithmetic limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Once the bug is resolved `-0` will not scare unnecessarily any more. But until then...

You can adapt the snippet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11010869/6573902):

```
def real_norm(no):
    return no if no != 0 else abs(no)
    
def imag_norm(ino):
    return complex(real_norm(ino.real), real_norm(ino.imag))

test_cases = [-0-3j, 0-3j, -0-0j, 0-0j, -0+0j]
for tc in test_cases:
    tn = imag_norm(tc)
    print(f"{tc} -> {tn}")
```